# Django media files not showing with Debug = False on production - Django 1.10

Tags: django, static, media, collectstatic

I currently have two kind of files static files and media files.The static files contain my css,js and other static content. The media files contain stuff that the user uploads.The static folder is right next to the media folder.Now on my deployed machine. If I set the `DEBUG = False` my static files are presented just fine however my media content is never displayed. I get a `404 not found` error.
My quuestion is how do I display media content in production environment when DEBUG = False. With DEBUG= True everything seems to work fine ? I read the following [page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/) and tried these things out.

**1-Tried creating a separate folder for static media just like static content.**
Currently my static content is being managed by the `collectstatic` command. I am using apache on webfaction.I have a static folder called `static_content` when I ran `./manage.py collectstatic` all of my content in static folder was copied to the `static_content` folder.I tried creating another static folder called `static_media`. However when I ran `./manage.py collectstatic` the content of my `media` folder got copied to `static_content` and not to `static_media` like it should have. Can anyone tell me why the collectstatic command did not paste the content to `static_media` instead ?

This is what my configuration looks like

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
   "*",
   'mywebsite.com',
   'www.mywebsite.com.com',
]


STATIC_URL = 'http://mywebsite.com.com/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/admin/webapps/static_content'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
                        '/home/admin/webapps/mainfolder/mainapp/static',
                        '/home/admin/webapps/mainfolder/mainapp/media',
                   )
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_URL = 'http://mywebsite.com.com/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/admin/webapps/static_media'
```

This is what my urls.py looks like

```
admin.autodiscover()
urlpatterns = [
....
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Am I using the correct approach creating a separate folder for managing my media content just like for my static content for when DEBUG=False ? If so then why is collectstatic command dumping all my media content into my `static_content` folder instead of `static_media` folder ? Also if I use a static folder for managing my media content when a user uploads data where will that be uploaded to `media` or `static_media`.

Comment: Note you don't need `admin.autodiscover()` in Django 1.7+

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Seems like I gorgot to mention Django version I was using. I just added it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You shouldn't use `collectstatic` for your media directory. Remove `'/home/admin/webapps/mainfolder/mainapp/media'` from `STATICFILES_DIRS`, then set

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/admin/webapps/mainfolder/mainapp/media'
```

Once you've done this, the `static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` should serve media files when `DEBUG = True`.

For `DEBUG = False`, you have to [configure Apache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files) to serve the media files.

Comment: I already have the media files working for DEBUG = True. I guess Ill have to configure apache.

Comment: Didn't sound like it was working in your question - "If I set the DEBUG = True my static files are presented just fine however my media content is never displayed"

Comment: Ah thanks for catching that. I just fixed it. I am trying to figure out how I can configure a httd.conf I cant find apache2,conf in my deployment server

Comment: The location of your apache config depends on the operating system (and perhaps your hosting provider if you are using shared hosting). That's really a separate question, so I can't help you with that.

Answer (score 27):

In your `urls.py` file:

add this line

```
from django.views.static import serve
```

add those two urls in urlpatterns:

```
url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
```

It worked for me :)

Comment: Shouldnt be used in production though: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/views/#serving-files-in-development

Comment: Exactly, souldn't be used in production: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/views/#serving-files-in-development

Answer (score 9):

If you are using Nginx, let it to serve media files

For **Example**

go to **nginx/sites-available** & add this

```
location /media/ { root */home/myprojectdir/myproject*; }
```

Comment: I managed to overlook this, and it might have not been the fix for most people but thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I have faced the same issue with `DEBUG=False`. I solved it by configuring Nginx media location in the server block like this

```
location /media/ {
    root FULL_PATH_TO_APP; 
}
```

**FULL_PATH_TO_APP** is the full path to the directory where my `media` folder exists.

Answer (score 3):

In Pythonanywhere server
Just
add Static file **url** and **Directory**

**URL**
/static/
/media/

**Directory path**

/home/taukir707/myblog/static

/home/taukir707/myblog/media

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution. Keep you media folder inside your static folder. And use this code in

> Settings.py

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/
if(DEBUG==True):
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    MEDIA_URL = '/static/media/'
    STATICFILES_DIRS=[
         os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
    ]
    STATIC_ROOT='/home/username/websitedomain/static'
    MEDIA_ROOT='/home/username/websitedomain/static/media'
else:
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    MEDIA_URL='static/media/'
    STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
    MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static/media/')
```

Comment: runserver can't serve media if MEDIA_URL is within STATIC_URL.

Answer (score 0):

this helps me a lot

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'


STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")


MEDIA_URL =  '/media/'


MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")


STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedStaticFilesStorage'


INSTALLED_APPS = [
 
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',

]
```

in url.py import URL and give static and media file URL

```
from django.views.static import serve

from django.conf.urls import url
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

1. In settings.py:
   `DEBUG = False`
2. In urls.py :

```py
if not settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

3. `$> python manage.py runserver`

Work fine in deployment or development!

Answer (score 0):

devserver in secure mode

Step 1

Define a STATIC_ROOT and MEDIA_ROOT path in settings.py.

Code: settings.py

```
            STATIC_URL = '/static/'

            MEDIA_URL = '/media/'



            if DEBUG:

                  STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]

            else:

                  STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

            MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Step 2

Code: urls.py

```
            from django.conf.urls import url
            from django.conf import settings
            from django.views.static import serve

            urlpatterns = [
                  url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
                  url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
            ]
```

Then run py manage.py runserver

Answer (score 0):

Need to change Ngingx to add location:

```
location /media/ {
   alias /home/xuser/xproject/media/;
   expires 1d;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.