# Media files not displaying when DEBUG = False; what are the prerequisites to get them to show?

Tags: python, django, deployment, web-deployment, production-environment

As I state in the title, **when I set `DEBUG = False` in my project's settings file, the files from my `media` directory (the one the user uploads) don't display.** The files from my `static` directory (the CSS and JavaScript files) load properly.

I looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44555187/django-media-files-not-showing-with-debug-false-on-production-django-1-10), but I don't understand the prerequisites to get this to work. I am testing this on my local machine, where I only have Django and PostgreSQL installed. I don't have any Apache servers running, as far as I'm aware. I want to deploy my app on Amazon AWS, so I'd like to try out how it will look in production there before I deploy it to Amazon AWS.

Here are the relevant parts of my `settings.py` file:

```
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
   BASE_DIR / "static",
   '/var/www/static/',
]
```

Comment: Django does not serve static/media files in production.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61611017/67579

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem OK. I have two questions on this: 1) How is it then that my static files load properly? 2) What do I need to do in order to show my media files in production?

Comment: 1) caching? 2) set up the web server like apache/nginx to serve files.

Answer (score 0):

Willem Van Onsem is right on the media files. Since the static file is OK, for the workaround, you can add this line to your urls.py in the folder containing settings.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns+=static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```