# Images are not showing in Production ( DEBUG =False )

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere, django-settings

I Build a WebApp and I am stuck on a Problem.

> Images are not showing in Production (DEBUG = False)

settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT= '/home/new/gitrepo/main/media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = '/home/new/gitrepo/static/'
```

**What have i tried**

I tried `python manage.py collecstatic` BUT images are still not showing in the Website.

I found many answers on this Topic like [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44555187/django-media-files-not-showing-with-debug-false-on-production-django-1-). BUT it didn't  worked for me.

I don't know what i am doing wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: That is the expected behavior. Django does *not* serve static files in production. You need to configure Apache/Nginx/... to serve static files.

Comment: `collectstatic` only collects the static files in a directory.

Comment: BUT before days ago it worked and NOW it i a stuck on that problem

Comment: then likely this is due to caching, but as you can see (in the green box), Django deliberately does not do that for performance and security reasons https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files

Comment: AND i also don't know , How can i do Apache/Nginx, I've never worked with that

Comment: well that is the webserver that normally does the port forwarding to the Django application. Django runs on port 8000, so the webserver will forward incoming calls on port 80.

Comment: the configuration is explained In the linked documentation.

Comment: My `static files` are showing perfectly BUT only images are not displaying

Comment: @Progam check this post to serve media files on Nginx https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-serve-media-files

Comment: @Progam: that is likely because a browser will *cache* style files, javascript files, etc.

Comment: How does your Pythonanywhere static files mapping look like? Take a look at PythonAnywhere help page about Django static files https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DjangoStaticFiles

Comment: @Filip  Static file loading correctly BUT media and images are not loading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was it working in development? I think yes

open Pythonanywhere.com => choose "Web" from navbar => scroll to static files

and here you let pythonanywhere know where are the URLs for showing static data from your server

Add those two

```
URL                 Directory                     Delete

/static/            /home/myWebsite/static
/media/             /home/myWebsite/media
```

The `/home/myWebsite/media` is a path to where you store the static files for the given URL

here is a screenshot of my configurations
[image: My configurations]

If it's not showing make sure you have something in your main URLS.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Thanks, BUT it wasn't working in `Debug = False` too .

Comment: Di i need to make a folder of `media` in the `directory in which manage.py` is stored ?

Comment: No, it should be in the root

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that the above is not working, are you sure you are putting the correct URL for the images? try to find the correct URL of the images manually then compare it with the url in the img src in your website and tell me the result

Comment: Thank you very much It WORKED