# Image not shown in debug for false in django

Tags: python, html, css, django, media

I want to run always in debug=false in django.
However, it works only when i turned to debug to true. Otherwise not.
In setting.py

```
     DEBUG = False
```

also, in setting.py

```
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    STATIC_ROOT = '/static/'
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'   
    if DEBUG:
        STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
    else:
        STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')   
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

In main urls.py

```
    from django.conf import settings
    from django.conf.urls.static import static  
    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('',include('mysite.urls')),
    ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I have directory of media, static, staticfiles in the directory where manage py is located.

If i put code exactly in apache will my code works. P.S In development also i want to fix debug as false always.

Comment: Django is not supposed to serve media or static files in production https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/ In DEBUG=False mode it is expected that media and static files dont work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django media files not showing with Debug = False on production - Django 1.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44555187/django-media-files-not-showing-with-debug-false-on-production-django-1-10)

Comment: Configure Apache / Nginx for serving these files in prod

Answer (score 0):

**Apache and Static/Media Files**

Are you running everything via Apache and mod_wsgi? If so, make sure to set your Apache ***conf*** files to handle the 'static' alias appropriately, and in so doing you should find that your setup works once you've run `python manage.py collectstatic`. (Example, assuming you host your project inside */var/www/myproject/*, is below):

```
Alias /static /var/www/myproject/static
    <Directory /var/www/myproject/static>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

You may need to do likewise for 'media' if your image is in your media directory.

---

**Development Server and Static/Media Files**

If you are still running the development server (i.e. `python manage.py runserver`) and you are doing so with `DEBUG = False`, then you will encounter issues serving static files and media files.

However, you can circumnavigate these issues by running `python manage.py runserver --insecure`, with the massive caveat that this is not ideal and expressly the opposite of a stable production set up - Django is not meant to serve these files in production.

---

**Final tip:**

If you are going to this trouble because you want a development server and a production server with different DEBUG values (i.e. True in development, False in production), an easy fix is to use the `django-environ` package plus a .env file, which you exclude from version control, and then set your DEBUG value inside your .env files. You'll then have a consistent settings.py file capable of returning DEBUG=True in development and DEBUG=False in production.

The link to this package is here: https://django-environ.readthedocs.io/en/latest/